# App crashes when a String or Character is entered

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type, swift-playground

I am a high school student interested in self-teaching. I have started learning swift for about 3 months now independently and it's my first time doing and learning how to code. So i thought of this super simple app idea which would only multiply two numbers which is provided in the text field, and the result is displayed after the button is pressed in place of the label. Here is the code for that:

```
import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var num1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var num2: UITextField!


@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let num1Entered: String? = num1.text
    let num2Entered: String? = num2.text

    var multiplyIt: Double? {

        return Double(num1Entered!)! * Double(num2Entered!)!

    }

    resultLabel.text = String(multiplyIt)

   }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

1. The variable resultLabel is the label which displays the result for two numbers when multiplied.
2. The variables "num1" and "num2" are the text fields which the user enters the numbers in which are then to be multiplied.
3. And the button "calculateButton" is the button which carries the multiplication action once pressed.

So my question is that when I run the app in the simulator and put a single character or a String, the app crashes. I know the reason because i force unwrap the value. I tried to safely unwrap it using "if let", but i couldn't get my way around it.

So can someone please help me or can tel me what should i do, with little changes made to the code I already have written.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with force unwrapping of nil values in this line:

```
return Double(num1Entered!)! * Double(num2Entered!)!
```

change it to something like this:

```
return (Double(num1Entered ?? "") ?? 0) * (Double(num2Entered ?? "") ?? 0)
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want custom behaviour in case no number has entered, use this scheme of code:

```
if let num1 = Double(num1Entered ?? ""), num2 = Double(num2Entered ?? "") {
    resultLabel.text = num1 * num 2
} else {
    resultLabel.text = "No valid number entered"
}
```

Comment: Its pretty much worked, and shows 0. But returns an optional except for a value. Like this ->  optional(0.0), but I want it to print the string "not a valid number" or something like that when I enter a non-double input like a string. Don't want "optional(0.0).

Answer (score 1):

Your label value is a string value, so you should convert string value to Double first. Then do your multiplication or some arithmetic funtions, then again you need to display it as a text, so then again convert it in to a string, like this :-

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {

 let num1Entered:Double = Double(num1.text)!
 let num2Entered:Double = Double(num2.text)!

 var multiplyIt: Double = num1Entered * num2Entered
 resultLabel.text = String(multiplyIt)
```

}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sure, i'll improve my answer :)